# OSError: Unable to locate Ghostscript on paths

Tags: python, operating-system, python-imaging-library, eps, pyzo

I tried to open an EPS image with Pyzo, I have installed PIL and Ghostscript (as I saw that it is necessary on some other website topics), my code is:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('''myimage.eps''')
im.show()
```

but when I run the code, Pyzo return me:

> OSError: Unable to locate Ghostscript on paths

I tried to look into it on several websites but it seems pretty complicated for a novice coding student.

Comment: This one fixes my issue: https://www.tutorialexample.com/fix-oserror-unable-to-locate-ghostscript-on-paths-for-python-beginners-python-tutorial/

Answer (score 10):

In case someone else encounters this issue: It seems that Ghostscript has not been added to the paths properly. For those running Win7, here is a fix:

Go to:
Control Panel -> System -> Advanced system settings -> Environment Variables...

Find the variable "PATH" -> Edit... -> add the path to your ghostscript binary folder, e.g.

> C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.22\bin\;

to the end of the variable. It should be separated from the previous entry by a semicolon.

I had to restart for the changes to take effect.

Comment: All this time I used `pip install ghostscript` thinking it would yield the same result. Apparently you have to manually download gs and set environment variables.

Answer (score 9):

You need **ghostscript**.

1. download: https://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html
2. Tell the variable(`EpsImagePlugin.gs_windows_binary`) what the path of EXE(`gswin64c`, `gswin32c`, `gs` ) it is. (*If you don't want to change the system path.*)

```py
from PIL import EpsImagePlugin
EpsImagePlugin.gs_windows_binary =  r'X:\...\gs\gs9.52\bin\gswin64c'
im = Image.open('myimage.eps')
im.save('myimage.png')
```

---

You can see the following on [PIL.EpsImagePlugin.py](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/ce3d69b/src/PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py#L132-L135)

```
# EpsImagePlugin.py

__version__ = "0.5"

...

gs_windows_binary = None  # 

def Ghostscript(tile, size, fp, scale=1):
    """Render an image using Ghostscript"""

    ...

    if gs_windows_binary is not None:
        if not gs_windows_binary:   # 
            raise WindowsError("Unable to locate Ghostscript on paths")
        command[0] = gs_windows_binary
```

So that's why I tell you to set the `gs_windows_binary` will work.