# Unable to locate Ghostscript on paths

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, ghostscript

```
    image_eps = 'test.eps'
    im = Image.open(image_eps)
    fig = im.convert('RGBA')
```

```
raise OSError("Unable to locate Ghostscript on paths")
OSError: Unable to locate Ghostscript on paths
```

the error comes from here:
EpslmagePlugin.py

```
    for binary in ("gswin32c", "gswin64c", "gs"):
        if shutil.which(binary) is not None:
            gs_windows_binary = binary
            break
    else:
        gs_windows_binary = False
```

shutil = module 'shutil' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\shutil.py'

unfortunately i did not find a solution for the problem here or anywhere else.

what have I found and what have I done so far:
[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44587376/oserror-unable-to-locate-ghostscript-on-paths?noredirect=1&lq=1)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfUPf.png)
i added the Path C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.50\bin\
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hdfX.png)

what I also don't quite understand is why pycharm gets the shutil from Microsoft Visual Studio.

Comment: Is there a `gs` in the directory you added to your PATH?

Comment: **How** did you add the extra PATH by the way?

Comment: Control Panel -> System -> Advanced system settings -> Environment Variables
Edit PATH: C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.50\bin\

I added some Pictures in the post

Comment: Did you restart your computer after changing the PATH? Might be worth a try.

Comment: the good old restart. Problem solved :)

Comment: You gotta love Windows