# how to save the canvas screen (tkinter) in the .png format?

Tags: tkinter

```
x = self.canvas.winfo_rootx() + self.canvas.winfo_x()
y = self.canvas.winfo_rooty() + self.canvas.winfo_y()
x1 = x + self.canvas.winfo_width()
y1 = y + self.canvas.winfo_height()
ImageGrab.grab().crop((x, y, x1, y1)).save(filename)
```

I am using this method but it does not capture the whole canvas screen

[it is saving like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enE2o.jpg)

and if i move the root window, the image it captures also changes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert canvas content to an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886274/how-can-i-convert-canvas-content-to-an-image)

Comment: no it isnt working for me

Comment: Are you getting an error? When you tried it does it save to the file? When I tried it (a while ago) I also had trouble setting it up. Did you try `AndyRichter`'s answer (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55385764/11106801))?

Comment: OSError: Unable to locate Ghostscript on paths.
This error shows up

Comment: Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44587376/oserror-unable-to-locate-ghostscript-on-paths)

Comment: It still isnt capturing the whole Canvas Widget and it also captures the background of the desktop.
the tkinter window looks like this https://imgur.com/a/LGXrvVz
and the image grab that happen is https://imgur.com/a/opDvMXD

Comment: When you tried: `<tkinter.Canvas>.postscript(file="file_name.eps", colormode="color")`, it gave you an `OSError`. Did you try to resolve it?

Comment: I don't want to save these images so i didn't try it.

Comment: In the code that you showed above you are saving it to file so I don't get what you mean by *"I don't want to save these images"*

Comment: i am trying to make the handwritten digit recognition application. I am using the tkinter for gpu. In the root window there will be 2 buttons(predict and clear_screen) and Canvas widget (where i draw the numbers). Now if i press the predict button, it will call an function that will grab the whole canvas widget of the root window and will show it on the another window of the opencv (using the imshow method of opencv library)

Comment: So save the contents of the `Canvas` as an image (using `<tkinter.Canvas>.postscript(file="file_name.eps", colormode="color")`) and then open them using `opencv`.