# Python TKinter: The canvas image file just contains one black pixel instead of 512x256 green pixels, why?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, tkinter-canvas

```
canvas_width = 512
canvas_height = 512
root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height)
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, canvas_width, canvas_height / 2, fill='green')
ps = canvas.postscript(colormode='color')
img = PIL.Image.open(io.BytesIO(ps.encode('utf-8')))
img.save("/home/test.png")
```

If you execute this code, you will see that the saved file, `test.png`, contains only one black pixel. Instead, it should contain 512x256 green pixels and 512x256 undefined-color pixels.

Do you know why?

Comment: Just add `canvas.update()` after `create_rectangle`

Comment: I have discovered this exactly when you posted your comment!

Comment: Well, then find an explaination and post an answer ;)

Comment: You can do it, I'd be glad to upvote & accept your answer my friend :-)

Comment: Read [Tkinter understanding mainloop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29158947/7414759)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to redraw the canvas events by using `canvas.update()` or `canvas.update_idletasks()` before capturing. The difference is that `update()` is processing user events while `update_idletasks()` is just forcefully redrawing the window. Only then you'd be able to capture a postscript since all the text and graphics will already be there to capture and convert it to an image.
Hope that's helpful!

Comment: Ty ! I just found out that my image is 386x386 instead of 512x512, do you know why?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53509131/tkinter-saving-canvas-at-wrong-scale)

Comment: @Jars Read [What's the difference between "update" and "update_idletasks"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29159152/7414759)