# How to create a pdf from tkinter canvas using ghostscript

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, tkinter, ghostscript, tkinter-canvas

I have a canvas object in Tkinter, and I would like to export that canvas as a PDF file. I hear ghostscript can be used, but I don't know how to do so. Can someone please give an example of usage?

EDIT
I've looked into the example below, but I get the error:

```
'ps2pdf' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
```

The code i used to test is:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import subprocess
import os

class App(tk.Tk):
   def __init__(self):
      tk.Tk.__init__(self)
      self.title("Canvas2PDF")
      self.line_start = None
      self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=300, height=300, bg="white")
      self.canvas.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: self.draw(e.x, e.y))
      self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Generate PDF",
                            command=self.generate_pdf)
      self.canvas.pack()
      self.button.pack(pady=10)

def draw(self, x, y):
    if self.line_start:
        x_origin, y_origin = self.line_start
        self.canvas.create_line(x_origin, y_origin, x, y)
        self.line_start = None
    else:
        self.line_start = (x, y)

def generate_pdf(self):
    self.canvas.postscript(file="tmp.ps", colormode='color')
    process = subprocess.Popen(["ps2pdf", "tmp.ps", "result.pdf"], shell=True)
    process.wait()
    os.remove("tmp.ps")
    self.destroy()
app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: This question has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17877495/python-tkinter-save-canvas-as-postscript-and-add-to-pdf).

Comment: @RolandSmith I've tried that, but it says ps2pdf is not recognized

Comment: have you installed ps2pdf on your system?

Comment: @BryanOakley how would I do that. I thought it was included in the ghostscript?

Comment: @OsasenagaEmokpae Note that if you are using ms-windows you should use `ps2pdf.bat` instead of `ps2pdf`. And you might need to call that with its full path in case its location isn't in your `$PATH`.  Or you can just call ghostscript with the right parameters directly instead.

Comment: @RolandSmith that's the problem, im not sure what parameters to place inside ghostscript, and there hasn't been much information online.

Comment: Ghostscript comes with its own documentation in ghostscript/doc, you can also find it at ghostscript.com. The PDF output device is called pdfwrite so you would do -sDEVICE=pdfwrite. Then you need to give it an output file, so -sOutputFile=/directory/file.pdf. Note that the Windows veraion of Ghostscript comes in 4 'flavours'; 32 or 64 bit, and window or command line version. So gswin32c, gswin64c, gswin32 or gswin64.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ghostscript directly.

My suggestion would be to use something like this:

```
args = ['gs', '-q', '-P-', '-dSAFER', '-dNOPAUSE', '-dBATCH',
        '-sDEVICE=pdfwrite', '-sOutputFile=result.pdf', '-c',
        '.setpdfwrite', '-f', 'tmp.ps']
process = subprocess.Popen(args)
```

Note that I'm **not** using `shell=True` here on purpose; it is not necessary in this case.

The arguments are based on reading the scripts that come with ghostscript, and the [documentation](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Readme.htm).

On ms-windows you might want to use `gs.exe` instead of just `gs`. Additionally you might have to use the full path to the ghostscript executable too, depending on how ghostscript was installed.